# new registration page refreshing without any changes

Tags: magento-1.9, register, supee-6788

I patched the **magento 1.9.0.1 with SUPEE-6788-1.9.0.1** now it is not registering customers. page simply refreshes and showing no error or any change.
I added the code

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
    **<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>**

<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php //echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>
```

To

```
   app/design/frontend/base/customer/form/register.phtml
   app/design/frontend/base/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
   app/design/frontend/base/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

i am using an extension clarion and changed it there as well

```
app/design/frontend/base/clarion/customerattribute/form/register.phtml
```

Still the issues has not been fixed. please help

Comment: Are you files path right ? It should be `app/design` and not `app/code/design`.

Comment: yes the file path are correct i wrote this manually and left with a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

There's several different steps here to take:

First, if you've applied the patch you don't need to edit templates under `app/design/frontend/base/default` as those are native Magento templates and are updated with the patch script.

Second, if you're using a custom theme with custom version of the templates you mentionned you will indeed need to update the following files:

- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/customer/form/register.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/customer/form/login.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`
- In your case there would be an extra template to edit due to the presence of a 3rd party module : `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/customerattribute/form/register.phtml`

For the `login.phtml` templates you need to update your code like this:

- Find this piece of code : `<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">`
- Add the following code right after it: `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

Regarding the `register.phtml` templates you need to:

- Find the following piece of code: `<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />`
- Add the following code right after it: `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

Regarding the `resetforgottenpassword.phtml` template I'm not aware that the form key must be added to it.

Comment: the registered customers are able to login and place order. Should i still add the code to login.phtml

Comment: If you're using a custom theme and the code I mentionned is not there, yes it's required

Comment: i use a custom theme and the login and register has been updated. Still the register page loads and with no errors and no sign up. is it something to do with cookie. i regret that i patched it with supee-6788

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys i finally fixed the issue. It was not the theme nor the extension did the problem. i had a old copy of my website back up replaced the app/code/core/mage/customer/controllers/AccountController.php  which has fixed the issue. hope it helps.